# Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_l$ be a continuous function then what is $f$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_l$ be a continuous function then what is $f$?

My conjecture is that $f$ will be all forms of increasing continuous monotone functions.

Let us pick a basis element of the form $[a,b)$ such that $f^{-1}[a,b)$ will be $[f^{-1}(a),f^{-1}b)$ .

Now, $[f^{-1}(a),f^{-1}(b))$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ [as $\mathbb{R}_l$ is finer than $\mathbb{R}$].

I think this will hold.

The basis of $\mathbb{R}_l$ is of the form $[a,b)$[It is the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$]

Will any continuous monotone function satisfying the above condition?

Comment: A half open interval is not an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.  I highly suspect the answer will be constant functions only, but not sure

Comment: Isn't $R_l$ finer than $R$ so the open sets in $R_l$ should be open in $R$?

Comment: $[0, 1)$ is not open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I don't have my copy of Munkres handy,  but no,  how would you write $[0,1)$ as a union of open intervals $(a,b)$? You can't

Comment: $\Bbb R_l$ is finer than $\Bbb R$, so the open sets in $\Bbb R$ are open in $\Bbb R_l$, not the other way around.

Comment: Oh I am making a problem in the definition. I get it

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, $f[\Bbb R]$ is connected....

Answer (score 2):

Any set of the form $[a,b)$ is clopen in $\Bbb R_l$ and the only clopen subsets of $\Bbb R$ are $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R$ (in the usual topology), due to connectedness of $\Bbb R$.

Show that it follows that such a continuous $f$ can only be constant.

Comment: is there any other way to show this without using connectedness?Connectedness is introduced in the later section of the book.

Comment: @Antimony Munkres asks this after treating connectedness.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_l$ is continuous and takes (at least) two values $a$ and $b$ with $a<b.$ This implies that $f^{-1}[a,b)$ and $f^{-1}[b,\infty)$ are both nonempty.

Now note that $\{ (-\infty,a), [a,b), [b,\infty) \}$ is a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of open sets in $\mathbb{R}_l.$ The properties of $f$ then implies that $\{ f^{-1}(-\infty,a), f^{-1}[a,b), f^{-1}[b,\infty) \}$ is a partition of open sets in $\mathbb{R}.$

But since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, the only possibility is then that exactly one of these three sets equals $\mathbb{R}$ and that the other ones are empty. That contradicts that $f^{-1}[a,b)$ and $f^{-1}[b,\infty)$ are both nonempty.

Thus $f$ can only take one value.